# Undefined methods in the extended class

Tags: php, google-maps, oop, curl

I have this code and I am extending a class but it says the method is undefined.

```
<?php
class api{
    //$api_Key;
    public function getURL($url){
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }
    public function postURL($url){
        $ch = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
    public function getJSON($json){
        return json_decode($json);
    }
} 
class geo extends api{
    public function getLocation(){
        return json_decode(postURL("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=$key"));
    }
}
class vote extends geo {
// Class properties and methods go here
}

?>
```

PHP file to view on web

```
<?php
        include("php/vote.php");
            $geo = new geo();
             echo $geo->getLocation();
        ?>
```

I am getting this error Fatal error:

> Call to undefined method geo::json_decode() in
>   G:\wamp\www\voting\php\vote.php on line 22

I have yet to find something that would help me solve this I have the parent and child classes right or I think I do.
It is extending the class so I am not sure why it is undefined any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

`json_decode()` is a built-in PHP function not a method of either of your classes.  You also forgot the `$this` reference for your method `postURL()`. Remove `$this` from `json_decode()` and use `$this->postURL`:

```
return json_decode($this->postURL("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=$key"));
```

But I assume you actually want to use your method `getJSON()`:

```
return $this->getJSON($this->postURL("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=$key"));
```

Comment: I still get this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function postURL() in G:\wamp\www\voting\php\vote.php on line 22

Comment: Edited `$this->postURL`